# Google Places API AutocompleteService sometimes doesn't know of certain street numbers, whilst Google Maps Search does

Tags: autocomplete, google-places-api, missing-data

I'm using Google Places Javascript API, the AutocompleteService for instance, to programmatically obtain results and populate my customized autocomplete (I do not use the default widget because I inject additional data in the results, coming from another API).

I've noticed that several streets plus specific numbers are well-known to Google Maps but unknown to the AutocompleteService.

In example, Google Maps knows where "Via Lorenzo Valla 42 Rome" is.
But submitting "Via Lorenzo Valla 42" to the getPlacePredictions() method produces no correct results; even though that submitting "Via Lorenzo Valla" returns the correct street in Rome, it doesn't do the same when a specific number is provided.

My code is very simple:

```
acpredictions.getPlacePredictions({input : request.term}, callback);
```

Can anyone help?

Thank you!